# Best Practices/Information Architecture for Super-Administrator Dashboard for SaaS product

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, ux-field, dashboard, administration

We are a B2B company building a SaaS product that allows clients (usually businesses in themselves) for meeting/conference room booking/display.

I am aware and have seen plenty of dashboards on the client side, but have never seen how Salesforce themselves handle all of their clients in their own dashboard which I'm sure they have or use. For example I may be the boss of a company with G-Suite (Google cloud services), but how does the UI and architecture of Google's super-admin view of all client accounts look like?

This is one step above what most designers and developers are creating, but we are just curious as to what best practices may be. If they differ at all from how one would create a dashboard for client-administrator uses. As a super admin there are some nuances and we would like to make sure we aren't missing anything. In terms of the categories for navigation on the dashboard, the types of widgets we would have for displaying quick analytics, etc.

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

## Support the workflow

There's nothing special about the super user other than having more access.
They still have work to do and your app needs to support that.
How is their work different from regular admins? **Ask your users.**

Evaluate their context(s),
the work they regularly complete,
what their goals are,
and map it all out.

Find where all of that intersects your product (or where your product *should* intersect with it) and build views and features that support those needs.

Comment: Thanks plainclothes for your response! By "Ask your them" did you mean ask my users? or ask the potential admins? Just clarifying
This is all good advice

Comment: Sorry, stupid typo in the midst of a busy morning. Ask the users and devine the appropriate workflows from their stories. Guessing can only get you so far with a prototype.